# MySQL subquery to get a value from a table based on id from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write up a `subquery` in order to retrieve a `client name` from the `clients` table by using a `client_id` from the `orders` table.

- 1st query:

`SELECT client_id, order_id, deadline, state FROM orders GROUP BY order_id`

- 2nd query:

`SELECT name FROM clients WHERE id=:client_id`

- What would the 2nd query look like as a `subquery` into the first in order to display final results like the following, adding the `name` from the `clients` table based on each `client_id` from `orders` table matching `id` from the `clients` table:

`client_id` - from `orders` table

`order_id` - from `orders` table

`deadline` - from `orders` table

`state` - from `orders` table

`name` - from `clients` table

`grouped by order_id` from `orders` table

Comment: (SELECT name FROM clients WHERE id=orders.client_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to get second table's `name` value in your result set. Then you have to get values from 2 tables. Using subquery is the one solution:

```sql
SELECT o.client_id, o.order_id, o.deadline, o.state, c.name 
FROM orders o, clients c
WHERE (c.id = o.client_id)
GROUP BY o.order_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

##### JOIN Clause

```sql
SELECT o.client_id,
       o.order_id,
       o.deadline,
       o.state,
       c.name
FROM orders o
         join clients c on c.id = o.client_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

##### GROUP BY

SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. You'd better use this:

```sql
SELECT o.client_id,
       o.order_id,
       o.deadline,
       o.state,
       c.name
FROM orders o
         join clients c on c.id = o.client_id
GROUP BY o.client_id,
         o.order_id,
         o.deadline,
         o.state,
         c.name
```